# Solving $\tan^4 x+\cot^4 x+\cot2x=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve for $x$:
>   $$\tan^4 x+\cot^4 x+\cot2x=2$$

I have tried some formula with $\cot 2x=\dfrac{\sin^2 x-\cos^2 x}{\sin x \cos x}$, but I do not know what to do.

Comment: What is the question? Solve for $x$?

Comment: Yes, solve for x of course sir!

Comment: In your formula, you want $\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$ on the numerator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $\tan^4x+\cot^4x$ and $\cot2x$ are periodic with period $\frac\pi2$, we will let $z=\tan x$ and assume $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ so $z>0$.

Then, using $\tan2x=\frac{2z}{1-z^2}$, the equation becomes
$$z^4+\frac1{z^4}+\frac{1-z^2}{2z}=2$$
Multiplying out denominators and factoring, we get
$$(z-1)(z+1)(2z^6+2z^4-z^3-2z^2-2)=0$$
So we have one solution $x=\frac\pi4$. The other solution corresponds to the positive, irreducible root of the sextic, and is $x=0.816487\dots$

Answer (score 0):

My solution: 
$$tan^4x+cot^4x+cot2x=2$$

Lemma: $$cot2x=\frac{1}{2}(cotx-tanx)$$

$$<=>cot2x=\frac{1}{tan2x}=\frac{cos2x}{sin2x}=\frac{cos^2x-sin^2x}{2sinx.cosx}=\frac{cosx}{2sinx}+\frac{sinx}{2cosx}=\frac{1}{2}(cotx-tanx)$$

as desired.

Applying the lemma, I get: $$(tan^2x-cot^2x)^2=\frac{tanx-cotx}{2}$$

$$<=>(tanx-cotx)[(tanx-cotx)(tanx+cotx)^2-\frac{1}{2}]=0$$

$$=>tanx=cotx$$ or $$(tanx-cotx)(tanx+cotx)^2-\frac{1}{2}=0$$

$$<=>x=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{k\pi}{2}$$ or $$(tan^2x-cot^2x)(tanx+cotx)=\frac{1}{2}(2)$$

Consider (2): $$tan^3x-cot^3x-cot^2tanx+cotxtan^2x=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$<=>(tanx-cotx)[(tanx-cotx)^2+3]+(tanx-cotx)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Set $tanx-cotx=t$

$$=>t^3+4t-\frac{1}{2}=0$$

$$=>t\approx 0.12452$$

$=>x\approx k\pi-0.754309$ and $x\approx k\pi+0.816487$

Comment: MathJax/Latex tip: write `\tan` instead of `tan` to get $\tan$ instead of $tan$. This works for most trigonometric functions (and other common functions too).